# How does ES multiple random queries without repeating the results?

Tags: elasticsearch

> elasticsearch version 5.0

I have a requirement to randomly query user information multiple times, but the final result cannot have duplicate data.

For example,

the first random query result

> user0 user1 user2

the second random query result

> user0 user3 user4

User0 is a duplicate.

This is my random query, how can I modify it?

```
{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [

    ],
    "excludes" : [ ]
  },
  "sort" : [
      {
      "_script" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "Math.random()",
          "lang" : "painless"
        },
        "type" : "number",
        "order" : "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ext" : { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
   "size": 1,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "random_score": {
                  "seed": "1477072619038"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

[You can follow this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bool must_not](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query and an [id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) query to remove the ids of the previously retrieved documents.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
      "boost": 1.0
    },
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [The set of previous Ids]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```